# How to plot the result of a regression prediction in R

Tags: r, regression

I am beginning with ML in R, and I really like the idea of visualize the results of my calculations, I am wondering how to plot a Prediction.

```
library("faraway")
library(tibble)
library(stats)

data("sat")
df<-sat[complete.cases(sat),]

mod_sat_sal <- lm(total ~ salary, data = df)
new_teacher <- tibble(salary = 40)
predict(mod_sat_sal, new_teacher)
```

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Data and Regression Model

```
data(sat, package = "faraway")
df <- sat[complete.cases(sat), ]
model <- lm(total ~ salary, data = df)
```

#### Method (1) : `graphics` way

```
# Compute the confidence band
x <- seq(min(df$salary), max(df$salary), length.out = 300)
x.conf <- predict(model, data.frame(salary = x),
                  interval = 'confidence')

# Plot
plot(total ~ salary, data = df, pch = 16, xaxs = "i")
polygon(c(x, rev(x)), c(x.conf[, 2], rev(x.conf[, 3])),
        col = gray(0.5, 0.5), border = NA)
abline(model, lwd = 3, col = "darkblue")
```

[image]

---

#### Method (2) : `ggplot2` way

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = salary, y = total)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]